# Fixed header with blur effect,what i am doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make a page like this

[image]

Header should be fixed, and `bg-image` should be fixed too, I did that. The only problem I have is, how to make exactly the same blur. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="header"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cumque, esse eum facere illum iste maxime neque omnis saepe temporibus totam veritatis! Asperiores, dignissimos illum in labore libero nihil saepe!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cumque, esse eum facere illum iste maxime neque omnis saepe temporibus totam veritatis! Asperiores, dignissimos illum in labore libero nihil saepe!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cumque, esse eum facere illum iste maxime neque omnis saepe temporibus totam veritatis! Asperiores, dignissimos illum in labore libero nihil saepe!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And here is SASS

```
@mixin background($imgpath,$position:0 0,$repeat: no-repeat)
  background:
    image: url($imgpath)
    position: $position
    repeat: $repeat

html, body
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  padding: 0
  margin: 0

.bg-image
  @include background('http://imgur.com/sTO5GYX')
  background-size: cover
  background-attachment: fixed
  display: block
  height: 500px
  width: 100%
  z-index: 1
  .header
    @include background('http://imgur.com/sTO5GYX')
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    z-index: 2
    background: rgba(153, 184, 208, 0.3)
    height: 50px
    display: block
    width: 100%
    filter: blur(2px)
.content
  height: 1500px
  display: block
  width: 100%
  text-align: center
```

Comment: what happens with the above code?

Comment: @Lal i  got this result http://imgur.com/EibQl9x

Comment: increase your opacity value..

Comment: @Lal i tryied,its not look as on image what i need anyway

Comment: ok..try `filter:blur(5px);` instead of opacity..is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lal did you saw image what i attached?Its a little bit different than just with blur effect, i am not sure what is it.

Comment: sorry...it is really difficult to understand the difference with these images..

Comment: what is the goal on here?

Comment: @freestock.tk make header background exactly the same as here http://i.stack.imgur.com/czJkW.jpg

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue **only post the compiled CSS**.

Comment: @commanon,okay got you.Thanks
Maybe you can help me with another question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733757/what-should-i-use-to-make-this-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2023 UPDATED ANSWER USING background-filter instead:**

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(255,204,255);
  margin: 0%;  
}
    
.bg1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/tWZjcIp.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg1"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Layers:
**1**- regular background image;
**1.5**- solid color layer to avoid blured borders when facing a white background;
**2**- clone of this with blur (reduced height);
**3**- white layer with low opacity (reduced height);

The use of the brightness filter on the **layer 2** is optional (according to the pic):

```
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) brightness(120%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: blur(5px) brightness(120%);
```

[**jsfiddle 1 - regular bg;**](https://jsfiddle.net/3e8qt7Lv/)

[**jsfiddle 2 - white bg;**](https://jsfiddle.net/k05y5wed/)

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(255,204,255);
  margin: 0%;  
}
    
.bg1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/tWZjcIp.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg1_5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  background: rgba(174,116,187,0.5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/tWZjcIp.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bg3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  background: rgba(255,204,255,0.1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg1"></div>

<div class="bg1_5"></div>

<div class="bg2"></div>

<div class="bg3"></div>
```

Comment: but look on my image its not just blur 5px,do you see the difference?

Comment: I was about to ask if the issue is, basically, the blured borders?

Comment: maybe,i have no idea,do you know how to do it?

Comment: updated: I made a div blur + div blur clone + div blur clone... etc; check the result.

Comment: its the same isnt it?

Comment: No, it isnt. And now i did add one more layer, re-check it please.

Comment: I didnt get exactly what you mean...but if you want it to scroll together with the page, use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`. The answer's description is updated.

Comment: yeah i know about position fixed,the problem is not here,i mean when i scroll it down on white fon its look weird also with blured borders.Try to add white block under image and scroll it

Comment: In fact the color I did use is *almost* white: #ffccff

Comment: I'll try to create a new layer between the original and the blur one, with a solid color (without alpha) to (maybe) reduce this issue.

Comment: It did work in my opinion, [**check the result**](https://jsfiddle.net/00ttxzsw/)

Comment: the answer description is now updated again with this new 1_5 solid color layer. Also with this new jsfiddle.

Comment: I was testing it here.. you can reduce the alpha of the **layer 1_5** rgb from 1 to 0.5 to get a better result on both backgrounds (image and white). ps: choose carefully the colors of the layers **1_5** and **3**. They are different in your layout since i did use a different image.

Comment: yeah i know,i used different color